# Get GC log data from the Docker container using jstat

Tags: java, docker, garbage-collection, jvm, jstat

I have a java application running inside a docker container with OpenJDK11. I want to get GC data from this application using `jstat` tool (available inside a container). Any idea how can I achieve this from the host or another container running on the same host?

Thank you :)

Comment: so you cant sh into it?

Comment: Is it possible without sh?

Comment: `docker run --entrypoint`, I guess. But if you really care about gc stats/logs, may be mount a folder in docker and output GC logs in there

Comment: Actually, I have a go script. I pass process_id to this go script. The script will collect data from the given process_id. Say I want to do sh from the go script then first I think I need to find out the container_id where the given process is running. Am I right?

Comment: if you have a script, it has to be in the docker container, not outside it. the process_id is only known to the host, not externally

Answer (score 0):

The processes are visible on the host, so `jstat -gcstat <pid>` works on the host if you know the pid as it is seen by the host.

You can get the host-pid of a container-pid-1 via `docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' <container name>` and then walk the process tree (e.g. via `/proc` or some library encapsulating that logic) to find the java child process and then call jstat.

Another option is to (partially) join the container's namespace via `nsenter` or `docker exec` and then just execute `jps` and `jstat` inside the container. But that can be a security concern if you don't trust the container.

Comment: Thanks, @the8472. I don't have ```jstat (JDK)``` on the host. It is available inside a container where the target java process is running. So I think somehow from the host I will need to identify the container and do ```docker exec```. As you suggested I can try ```docker inspect``` but I will need to figure out how to get ```<container-name>``` dynamically.